# Winscp put command and switch options

Tags: batch-file, automation, sftp, put, winscp

Hi there I am using sftp via winscp to transfer all files that end in .txt to a directory on a remote server.  The problem I am having is I am getting an error on the file for permissions and timestamp.

I am trying to add two switches to the put command "-nopreservetime -nopermissions" but I am unsure of the correct sequence.

```
open sftp://username:password@myftp.com/ -hostkey="ssh-dss 1024 95:98:cb:3c:90:7b:bf:b4:3f:c3:72:b5:04:2b:b2:39" -rawsettings FSProtocol=2

# Change the Local Directory 
lcd "F:\Heartland" 
# Change to the correct Remote directory 
cd "/Distribution/Positive Pay1"
# List the local files 
lls 
# List Remote Files 
ls 
# Upload *.txt 
put -nopreservetime -nopermissions "*.txt" 
# Disconnect 
close 

exit
```

Comment: Your code is correct. If it does not work, show us log file: `winscp /log=log.log /script=...`.